# Swift - Store fonts' size, color, name, etc. in a file accessible by every class?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a quite big application with many controllers and I'm facing an issue regarding the design. For example, when I have a controller containing a UITextView, a UILabel, a UIButton with a title, etc., I write a function taking the screen size as an argument so that the size of the fonts I want to use is adapted to the device that runs the app. This method is quite tedious and redundant! 
Would you have any suggestions on how to set all my design settings for the whole application once and for all and make them accessible by all my classes? Do I have to store everything on UserDefaults, use some kind of a big data file, use Core Data, ... ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a larger font just because the screen is larger.

Comment: Are you using Swift or Obj C?

Comment: @Sharath obviously  its SWIFT, as it tagged

Comment: i think you dont require to set fontsized base on screen size

Comment: Using singleton or large data/static class file will increase your speed, accessing values from Coredata or defaults will need to read the data from the storage which is more expensive than in memory. If you want to use core data then you might want to use persistent store as In-Memory instead of sqlite.

Comment: Just create 1 swift file with no initializers and declare the constants which you want it may be text,font,color etc.. and use it as it in your file anywhere in your app. it will be globally accessible.

Comment: @Sweeper My question is not only for font size but I'm interested by your answer. Why shouldn't I adapt the font to the screen size? When I use auto-layout, the result is okay but not really ideal... I thought it would be more interesting to handle this myself so that the result meets my expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I somehow mistaken your code to be in Objective-C so my answer is targeted to it. You might still find it useful, convert it to swift so I am posting it anyway. (I have no time at the moment to rewrite it, apologies).

I am not sure why you would need to save these values as it seems you may recreate them anytime the app opens. And if you would save them and user would migrate from backup to another device then these settings would be copied as well but I assume values would need to change on devices of different size (going from iPhone 7 to iPhone 7+).

**About saving:**

Core data seems a complete overkill. User defaults might not be the best place either so I suggest you to simply use a JSON file. `NSJSONSerializer` has an option to serialize a dictionary into `NSData` which may be written into library directory. It can also then extract the dictionary back from that file.

**About accessing:**

There are a few nice ways but in any case I suggest you to create a singleton like `AppearanceManager` which will hold all the data. From saving into JSON you would at some load time call `[[AppearanceManager sharedInstance] loadFileNamed:@"nameOfTheFile"]`.

Then I suggest one of 2 ways. First is to have a property for each of the font types (you can use other things like colors as well) so you would call `[AppearanceManager sharedInstance].titleFont`. This is pretty nice but very friendly for saving though.

The other way is to use enumerations so you would call `[[AppearanceManager sharedInstance] fontOfType:FontTypeTitle]`. This one will give you a bit more power in objective-C (in Swift it is a bit crappier again).

**Saving and enumerations:**

If you use enumerations in Objective-C as integers you have this great trick where you always keep `count` as the last enumeration:

```
typedef enum {
   FontTypeNormal,
   FontTypeTitle,
   // Add others here

   FontTypeCount
}FontType;
```

Now assume you have a method `fontForType:(FontType)type` you can extract your whole JSON file like

```
for(int i=0; i<FontTypeCount; i++) {
    NSString *fontKey = [self keyForFontType:i];
    NSString *font = [self fontForType:i];
    dictionaryToSave[fontKey] = [self convertFontToDictionary:font];
}
```

This code will never break for you when adding or removing fonts as you keep the `FontTypeCount` as the last value in the enumeration and you never assign integer values to enumerations manually.

The rest should be pretty simple then. You would have a method that returns `keyForFontType` which is a simple `switch` statement. Same goes for returning a font for type which should most likely return a saved value or a default like:

```
UIFont *loadedFont = self.loadedJSONDictionary[[self keyForFontType:fontType]];
return loadedFont == nil ? [self defaultFontForType:fontType] : loadedFont;
break;
```

It is a bit of work at start but once you have all of these setup it should be very easy to work with this tool and is also highly portable to other projects.

Comment: Given that I'm used to dealing with JSON files, I really like your idea of using one of them! It sounds clean and efficient. I'm going to try it. Thanks!